# GCP Cloud Endpoints latency

Tags: proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, latency

The product overview of Cloud Endpoints states:

> Extensible Service Proxy delivers security and insight in less than 1ms per call.

But, I'm observing more than 10ms (maybe 100ms from time to time) added latency.

Our server settings are:

- we have a GKE cluster, which has:

  - a Kubernetes deployment for pods, each of which has an ESP container and our own container, which serves a gRPC service
  - a Kubernetes service (of `LoadBalancer` type) whose target refers to the ESP container
- we have an endpoint configuration for the gRPC service, which has only the basic stuff, as below.
- we issued an API key for clients

We had a client program in another GKE cluster in the same zone for this experiment.

With this setting, our experiments showed:

- with 15ms timeout on client's end, more than 95% calls were timed out
- on GCP's endpoints dashboard, majority of requests took more than 100ms
- on stackdriver trace, all the latency belongs to "Backend"
- when measured at our own container, the latency was below 5ms

The server's CPU load was very low (below 10%) and there is no sign of overloading at that time.

Assuming gRPC does not add much latency, we think the latency was probably from the ESP.

So, we ran another experiment with ESP-bypassed:

- we modified the Kubernetes Service in such a way that it refers to our own container, not the ESP container

After this fix, the latency measured at the client was dropped to 5ms.

So, if our experiments were correct, it seems the ESP container adds latency, far from 1ms, which is advertised at the product overview. Are we missing something?

Endpoint configuration:

```
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

name: foo.endpoints.bar.cloud.goog

title: foo in bar
apis:
- name: com.bar.FooService
```

Comment: Can you follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/troubleshoot-gke-deployment#checking_configuration_files) to check nginx.config to find any potential ESP misconfiguration?